# Convert string to an array in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, search, solr

How do I convert a string to an array so that it can be searched one by one. For example if the parameter passed is `puma shirts`,I want to split it as `puma` and `shirt` so that I can do solr search with `puma` in `table1` and get the ids. In the second chance I want to do solr search with `shirts` in `table1`. Here is the controller code that I'm currently using.

```
def search_all
    ids1=Array.new       

    @search1=Table1.search do
      fulltext params[:text]
    end

    @search1.results.each do |result|
      ids1 << result.id
    end
end
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-split) method to split a String into an Array:

```
> "this string has many words".split
 => ["this", "string", "has", "many", "words"]
```

You can pass an argument to `split` if you want to split on something other than whitespace, but the default should work for your case.

I haven't actually used Solr before (or Sunspot, which appears to be the standard way to integrate it with Rails), so this is just a guess, based on a brief glance at it and at the code you include, but I imagine you'd do the search something like this (assuming I understand what you're trying to do):

```
search_terms = params[:text].split

@results = {}
search_terms.each do |search_term|
  search = Table1.search do
    fulltext search_term
  end
  @results[search_term] = search.results.map(&:id)
end
```

This should give you an instance variable Hash `@results` - it's keys are the terms searched for, and the value of each will be the ids of elements of Table1 that matched that term.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm able to split the string as you told. May I know how to do solr search on each split string and the ids from table1???

Comment: Here is the code that I modified. list=params[:text].split(/ /) list.each do |list| @search1[list]=Table1.search do fulltext list end end. but I'm getting the following error. undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass

Comment: You need to define `@search1` before assigning values to it. (`@search1 = {}`)

Comment: I defined it,But I'm not able to reteive their ids. How to fix this. here is the code.    if(@search1.nil?)
      @search1[list].results.each do |result|
        ids1 << result.id
      end
    end

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
search_terms = params[:text].split

@results = []
search_terms.each do |search_term|
  search = Table1.search do
    fulltext search_term
  end
  @results << search.results.map(&:id)
end
@results.flatten!.uniq!
```